# Jinja2 For Loop over a YAML List of Dictionaries

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2, nexus

I am fairly new to Jinja2 and I have an issue I can't seem to resolve no matter what I try. I am trying to create a config file for a device using a Jinja2 template and some variable files I have created. I cannot seem to get it working at all when I am specifying a list of dictionaries for my YAML variable file.

template:

```
{% for id in VLANS %}
vlan {{ id.id }}
  name {{ id.name }}
  vn-segment {{ id.vni }}
{% endfor %}
```

variable file:

```
VLANS:
  - id: 9
    name: "VLAN9"
    vni: 109
  - id: 10
    name: "VLAN10"
    vni: 110
  - id: 11
    name: "VLAN11"
    vni: 111
  - id: 12
    name: "VLAN12"
    vni: 112
```

Comment: Looks fine. Can you share the error you are getting, or the output file? Also might help to share the template task from your play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine. The play below

```yaml
    - name: Template
      template:
        src: template.j2
        dest: test.txt
```

gives

```sh
    shell> cat test.txt 
    vlan 9
      name VLAN9
      vn-segment 109
    vlan 10
      name VLAN10
      vn-segment 110
    vlan 11
      name VLAN11
      vn-segment 111
    vlan 12
      name VLAN12
      vn-segment 112
```

with template

```
    shell> cat template.j2
    {% for item in VLANS %}
    vlan {{ item.id }}
      name {{ item.name }}
      vn-segment {{ item.vni }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: My issue was that I had one VLAN farther down in my script that I was not specifying a VNI for because it is not participating in my VXLAN EVPN fabric. Seeing you use item instead of id was a big help for me as I have a lot to learn about Jinja, thank you!

My template task was the exact same as yours but the error I was previously receiving in Ansible was as follows:

"msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'vni'"

I am going to play around with creating an if statement inside my for loop for any VLANS that do not have a vni defined. Thanks again!!

Comment: Simple option how to handle undefined variables is [default filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defaulting-undefined-variables). Example: *item.vni|default('NOT DEFINED')*